# How to hide 4 hours ahead in select option

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime

```
 echo '<select required name="time" id="time" class="time">';
    $start = strtotime($this->helper->getOpeningTime());
    $end = strtotime($this->helper->getClosingTime());

    for ($calltime = $start; $calltime <= $end; $calltime = $calltime + 30 * 60) {
        $disabled = '';
        $time = date('H:i', $calltime);
        $time_with_am_pm = date('g:i a', $calltime);
        printf('<option class="time" value="%s" >%s</option>', $time, $time_with_am_pm);

    }
    echo '</select>';
```

This is the code I am using and

```
$start = strtotime($this->helper->getOpeningTime()); - 09:00

$end = strtotime($this->helper->getClosingTime()); - 18:00
```

I want to add two more steps:
Let's say a user comes at 10 am and try to pick a time slot I want to disable the time from 10 am - 2 pm whatever is in between this time need to be disabled is that possible?

If the current time is 10 am how do I disable 09:00 and 09:30

**Desired output:**

> If the user comes at 10 am I want to disable 4 hours ahead so I want to disable 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30 13:00, 13:30, 14:00 and 14:30

Comment: Try to explain more about your desired output. You wanna see all the hours without 4-hours-window? 9.00, 9.30, 10.00, 02.00, .. 06.00?

Comment: No @AksenP That's wrong,
I want to well I want to try to show this -> There are two steps i want to take which are : 
If a user comes at 10 am I want to hide the past time which is 9:00 and 9:30 (This has to be disabled if it can be or if it's possible).
If the user comes at 10 am I want to disable 4 hours ahead so I want to disable 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30 13:00, 13:30, 14:00 and 14:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have skipped old time and time from 10 am to 2 PM, Please check the below code

```
<?php

    echo '<select required name="time" id="time" class="time">';
    $start = strtotime('09:00');
    $end = strtotime('18:00');
    $notA = date($format, strtotime("$date + 4 hours"));
    for ($calltime = $start; $calltime <= $end; $calltime = $calltime + 30 * 60) {

        $disabled = '';
        $time = date('H:i', $calltime);
        $time_with_am_pm = date('g:i a', $calltime);
        if($calltime > time()+60*60*4)
        printf('<option class="time" value="%s" >%s</option>', $time, $time_with_am_pm);

    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: i can't do this way 
you are manually removing     $skip = array('10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','14:00');

what happens if the user comes at 11 am?

But i do appreciate how you done this

Comment: I thought you want to remove 10 am to 2pm and all old times from your question

Comment: I said this as an example -> Let's say a user comes at 10 am and try to pick a time slot I want to disable the time from 10 am - 2 pm whatever is in between this time need to be disabled is that possible?

Comment: Whatever, this is not an answer. And what `$date` does do in your code? Also `$notA` and `$format`.

Comment: @jibingeorge So what times should be disable when he comes at 11:20 AM

Comment: @Ajith if a user comes at 11:20 I want to hide 11:30 12:00 12:30 13:00 13:30 14:00 14:30 I only show the time with 30 mins

Comment: @AksenP I have told you $date was a mistaken code I added in and $notA I have removed that line from my code the very first time you asked me and you did delete the message after I replied so I deleted mine

Comment: @jibingeorge, it was comment not to you)

Comment: I apologize for that, I didn't know

Comment: @jibingeorge I have added the modified the code to skip the next 4 Hours, Does it helps you?

Comment: @Ajith It's no returning any time

Comment: That is because current time + 4 hours doesnt fall in between 9 am to 6pm . Please try to give with few examples in your question

Comment: @Ajith I have gone through the code you have posted and It's correct, I didn't look at it properly it was my fault and thank you.

Comment: @jibingeorge Welcome, Could you please upvote my answer please

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need [one specific function](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/756/how-to-round-up-down-to-nearest-10-or-5-minutes-of-datetime-in-php):

```
function roundUpToMinuteInterval($dateTime, $minuteInterval = 10)
{
    return $dateTime->setTime(
        $dateTime->format('H'),
        ceil($dateTime->format('i') / $minuteInterval) * $minuteInterval,
        0
    );
}
```

Then you can transform each time point which will help you to get such kind of result:

```
   // $s1 = new DateTime(); 
    $s1 = new DateTime(date('H:i', strtotime($came_at)));   // should be comment
    echo 's1 = '.$s1->format("H:i").PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

   // $s2 = new DateTime(); 
    $s2 = new DateTime(date('H:i', strtotime($came_at)));   // should be comment
    $s2 = $s2->modify("+4 hour")->modify("+1 hour");       // +4 +1 
    echo 's2 = '.$s2->format("H:i").PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

    $start1 = date('H:i', strtotime($start));
    $end1 = date('H:i', strtotime($end));
    echo 'start1 = '.$start1.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'end1 = '.$end1.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

    $s3 = new DateTime($start1);  
    $s4 = new DateTime($end1);        
    $tmp_time = $s1->format("H:i");
    // correction time   
    $tmp = roundUpToMinuteInterval($s1, 30);    

    if ($tmp->format("H:i") === $tmp_time) {
        $s1 = $s1->modify("+1 minutes");  
    } else { 
        $s2 = $s2->modify("-30 minutes"); 
    }
```

Then you can use `while loop` like below:

```
    while ($s1 < $s2){

       //  echo $s1->format("H:i").PHP_EOL;
       //  echo $s2->format("H:i").PHP_EOL;

        if ($s1 <= $s4 && $s1 > $s3){

            $time1 = $s1->format("H:i").PHP_EOL;    // current time
            echo 'current time = '.$time1;

            $d = roundUpToMinuteInterval($s1, 30); // round minutes to the next half
            $time =  $d->format("H:i").PHP_EOL;
            echo 'upper-rounded time = '.$time;

            $time_with_am_pm = $d->format('g:i a').PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;   // AM/PM time
            echo 'AM/PM time = '.$time_with_am_pm;   

         //   printf('<option class="time" value="%s" >%s</option>', $time, $time_with_am_pm);
        }

        $s1 = $s1->modify("+30 minutes");  // next iteration with next half-hour
    }
```

Output:

```
s1 = 10:00

s2 = 15:00

start1 = 09:00

end1 = 18:00

current time = 10:01
upper-rounded time = 10:30
AM/PM time = 10:30 am

current time = 11:00
upper-rounded time = 11:00
AM/PM time = 11:00 am

current time = 11:30
upper-rounded time = 11:30
AM/PM time = 11:30 am

current time = 12:00
upper-rounded time = 12:00
AM/PM time = 12:00 pm

current time = 12:30
upper-rounded time = 12:30
AM/PM time = 12:30 pm

current time = 13:00
upper-rounded time = 13:00
AM/PM time = 1:00 pm

current time = 13:30
upper-rounded time = 13:30
AM/PM time = 1:30 pm

current time = 14:00
upper-rounded time = 14:00
AM/PM time = 2:00 pm

current time = 14:30
upper-rounded time = 14:30
AM/PM time = 2:30 pm
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gb0pT)**